# How to replace tag names in XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, replace

I'm new to XML, so this might be an easy question.
I have a XML file structured as below.

```
<root>
 <Test>
   <EmpID>23</EmpID>
   <EmpName>Packman</EmpName>
   <EmpAge>33</EmpAge>
 </Test>
 <Test>
   <EmpID>34</EmpID>
   <EmpName>James</EmpName>
   <EmpAge>13</EmpAge>
 </Test>
 <Test>
   <EmpID>53</EmpID>
   <EmpName>Nedved</EmpName>
   <EmpAge>52</EmpAge>
 </Test>
<root>
```

I want to replace some of elements in the XML file like below

```
<root>
 <Test>
   <EmpID name="ID">23</EmpID>
   <EmpName name="Nickname">Packman</EmpName>
   <EmpAge name = "Age">33</EmpAge>
 </Test>
 <Test>
   <EmpID name="ID">34</EmpID>
   <EmpName name="Nickname">James</EmpName>
   <EmpAge name = "Age">13</EmpAge>
 </Test>
 <Test>
   <EmpID name="ID">53</EmpID>
   <EmpName name="Nickname">Nedved</EmpName>
   <EmpAge name = "Age">52</EmpAge>
 </Test>
</root>
```

So basically I want to relace or add? element to attribute.

ex)

```
<EmpID>value</EmpID> to <EmpID name="ID">value</EmpID>
```

I've tried some of references, but they didn't work for me.
Below is the one that I tried, but it replaces whole line.

```
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load("C:\\Test\\Test.xml");
XElement one = xdoc1.Descendants("EmpID").First();
one.ReplaceWith("EmpID name=NickName");
xdoc1.Save("C:\\Test\\Test_Modified.xml");
```

The point is center 'value' should not change. See below.

```
<EmpID>value</EmpID> to <EmpID name="ID">value</EmpID>
```

Please give me some ideas how to solve this.

Comment: All you have to do is set the attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is set the [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
one.SetAttributeValue("name", "ID");
```

Comment: Thank you that works! I have one more question tho. What should I do if I want to change the name of attribute as well? for example, 'EmpID' to 'EmployeeID'. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `EmpID` is not an attribute, but the element name. You can use the `Name` propery to change that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To change the attribute you can go with above solution:

```
one.SetAttributeValue("name", "ID");
```

And the easiest way I found to rename a node is:

```
xmlNode.InnerXmL = newNode.InnerXml.Replace("OldName>", "NewName>")
```

Don't include the opening < to ensure that the closing  tag is renamed as well.

You can refer this link also:
http://www.goodgord.com/2006/10/how-to-rename-xml-node-in-c.html

Comment: This wouldn't work if the element has attributes, e.g. `<OldName foo="bar">`

Comment: Better use the `Name` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name%28v=vs.90%29.aspx